# How to make spring returns json array not a json object?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am returning a list from a method in a spring controller and the json output is json object not a json array?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/students")
public List<Student> getStudents() {

    List<Student> list = service.getStudents();

    return list;
}
```

What I get is a json object containing the json array.
`{ "students":[ { "name":"xyz" }, { "name":"xyz" }, { "name":"xyz" } ] }`

What I need a flat json array like this.

`[ { "name":"xyz" }, { "name":"xyz" }, { "name":"xyz" } ]`

Comment: I doubt that this compiles ... Additionally, Spring does not respond with an object if a list is returned. There is a great mismatch between the code shown here and the code you are actually running, I suppose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

return ResponseEntity:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/students")
public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getStudents() {
    List<Student> list = service.getStudents();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: This a another way of doing the same thing, but the effect would not be any different from the code that the OP shows (which itself can't possibly return what they say it is doing).